# Swift: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift

```
let healthWrite = Set(arrayLiteral:[
    HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex),
    HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned),
    HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning),
    HKQuantityType.workoutType()
])
```

Comment: Lookup the documentation. What is the return type of `quantityTypeForIdentifier()`? What does the question mark in `HKQuantityType?` indicate? What do you know about optionals and unwrapping?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor wants an array literal not an array so you'd init with something like this

```
let healthWrite = Set(arrayLiteral:
     HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex)!,
     HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)!,
     HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning)!,
     HKQuantityType.workoutType()
     )
```

More on arrays and array literal
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

EDIT:

It was the optional values that were giving you grief not the "[]"

```
let healthWrite = Set([
            HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex)!,
            HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)!,
            HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning)!,
            HKQuantityType.workoutType()]
            )
```

Better yet if you use a `guard` or `if let` to check that `HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier` actually returns a value before creating the set

Comment: You *can* create a `Set` from an array, `arrayLiteral:` is not needed at all.

Comment: You are right of course. But removing the brackets actually let the compiler suggest the unwrapping of the return values.

Comment: The `arrayLiteral` initialiser comes from the `ArrayLiteralConvertible` protocol and is intended to be used like this: `let healthWrite : Set = [item1, item2, ... ]`